# Total products ordered by each customer

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I have the following tables:

Customer (**custID**)

Order (**orderID**, custID)

PO (**prodID**, orderID, amount)

I would like to select each custID and the total amount of products ordered. I have the following code:

```
SELECT c.custId (COUNT(po.amount)) totalOrders
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN "Order" o
ON c.custId = o.custId
INNER JOIN PO po
ON o.orderId=po.orderId;
```

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot find either column "c" or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate "c.custId", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Answer (score 2):

You need a `group by`.  You don't need the customers table.  You want `SUM()`, not COUNT()`.  And your syntax is just off:

```
SELECT o.custId, SUM(po.amount) as totalOrders
FROM "Order" o INNER JOIN
      PO po
      ON o.orderId=po.orderId
GROUP BY o.custId;
```

Comment: The question was for Total amount of products, so COUNT() is probably correct, unless amount is the count of products on the order.

Comment: @TomC . . . If there is a column called `amount`, then "total amount" should refer to `sum(amount)`.

Comment: True - just wasn't sure if it was a badly worded question or not.  Anyway, the OP has both options now, sure they will work it out!